# Python2.7 - How to read a specific field in a MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb

I have some data stored in my collection, here is an example obtained through the shell. (Please ignore the language of the text.)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581ab1811d41c814004f4d16"),
    "created_time" : "2016-11-02T19:48:41+0000",
    "message" : "Acabaram de assaltar o carro de um colega nosso em Itabaiana\nno zangue, ele é de Aracaju e foi passear em Itabaiana.Gol G6 prata 2013 placa OER-5474.\n",
    "id" : "400728540046889_1107668596019543"
}
```

In this case I need to get only the text contained in the `"message"` field, since I need to do several operations in those texts. So the process would be as follows: In my collection I have to get all text in the  field `"message"`do the operations and then return this `"message"` to its proper location, along with its other attributes. My code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import preprocessing
import pymongo
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from unicodedata import normalize
from preprocessing import PreProcessing


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
    collection = client.facebook.dadosColetados1
    try:
        dbmessage = collection.find()
        for text in dbmessage:
            print text
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

I can not pass the `"message"` attribute to be used in find and when I use only `find()` it returns me the text without being in utf-8 like:

```
e7\xf5es institucionais para uma seguran\xe7a p\xfablica mais integrada em todo o Estado.\n\nO secret\xe1rio destacou a import\xe2ncia da manuten\xe7\xe3o do di\xe1logo entres as institui\xe7\xf5es.
```

What would be the best approach to this situation?

Edit1: Solution proposed by @jcmetz21 works.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us only a minimal working example? I took a quick glance and came to the conclusion that 95% of this code is unrelated. Brave young souls might be newly awake and up for the task, but lazy tired bums like me would think it's nice to not have to remove 95% of the code to test it locally if possible.

Comment: which version of python are you using? python 3: you could change messages to a `bytes` structure and then decode it as "latin-1". that would print the portugese (?) characters.

Comment: @Torxed I said I'd like to know how to use only the data contained in a field in the mongo collection. Once you get that data, do some operations and return it to the other data pertecentes to it. I gave an example of how this data is stored in the bank, gave an example of how I did to read and fetch that data. Only I can not return one text at a time.

Comment: @LeandroSantos As I said, 95% of all the content in `def status_processing(corpus):` could be removed from this example and still get your point across. It's only a recommendation, but keeping your examples short opens up your question to a whole bigger audience of helpers out there.

Comment: @Torxed Now i understand what you mean. I edited the code to get better.

Comment: What @Torxed meant is that your print statement will return a dictionary not your "message" which means that this is not the code you are running.

Comment: Ok @Styvane i tryed to change to this: 
`dbmessage = collection.find()
    for items in dbmessage:
        try:
            if "message" in items:
                print items[message]
        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the database and set the projection so just the value field associated with the "message" key is returned. Then throw the messages into a list.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost:27017')
db = client['db_name']

query = {'message': {'$exists': 1}}
projection = {'_id': 0, 'message': 1}

data = list(db['collection_name'].find(query, projection))

message_list = []
for message in data:
    for key, value in message.iteritems():
        message_list.append(value)
```

Now "message_list" will contain all of the messages from your collection and you can perform any operation on your data:

```
message_list = [u'message1', u'message2', u'message3', etc.]
```

EDIT#2 (note changes above): If you want to keep the id and timestamp associated to its respective message you can do the following...

In projetion, set the 'id' and 'created_time' key to 1 ('id': 1, 'created_time': 1) and change the code from above:

```
message_list = [value for dict in data for key, value in dict.iteritems() if key == 'message']
id_list = [value for dict in data for key, value in dict.iteritems() if key == 'id']
timestamp_list = [value for dict in data for key, value in dict.iteritems() if key == 'created_time']

# to print all of your messages
for message in message_list:
    print message
```

Now you can see all of your messages and do what you want with them, whether it be updating all of the messages through an iteration or updating a few messages though indexing.

Then you can pair up all 3 lists so you know what data is associated with what.

```
pair_up = zip(message_list, id_list, timestamp_list)

for x, y, z in pair_up:
    print "The message " + x + " has id " + y + " and timestamp " + z
```

Comment: Why will you use `find()` if what I want is create a list of 'messages' at the end of the day?’

Comment: Because first you need to find all of the documents in the database / collection that contains the "message" key. Or if you want to locate one specific message you can do that too by updating your query field.

Comment: And in the end I can then say that say, message 1 belongs to id x and so on?

Comment: @jcmetz21 How do I make the texts to be in utf-8? In mongo shell they are in utf-8, however if I display them through the code, they come out decoded. Example: `j\xe1 que s\xe3o `

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about the encoding. If you iterate through the list and `print` each part individually they should come out clean...`for i in updated_pair_up: print i[0], "corresponds to", i[1]`

Comment: Okay. But I need to read a text, do some operations and then get the ID and the timestamp. To always have the tuple id + text + timestamp. In the first example that you showed, I actually put it to give print at all, but not even putting the print, then I would have to convert to str to be able to do my operations. Not ideal. And when i print the `pair_up` my return is `[]`

Comment: @jcmetz21 If i print `value` the text ir encoded, but if i print `message_list` the output is a text like `j\xe1 que s\xe3o`

Comment: Which ID do you want - _id (which MongoDB automatically assigns) or id? Also I edited the code...let me know if that's what you're going for. Not sure about the encoding problem

Comment: Now I only need to know how the text will behave when I insert it. The last time I tried it, it said it was exceeding the size of the BSON in the Mongo. Maybe, I think he was trying to save the entire document as a single line of text.

Comment: Inserting data using python should look something like this: `new_data = db['collection_name'].insert_one( { 'created_time': datetime.datetime.now(), 'message': 'some message', 'id': 'some id' } ). Make sure to import the datetime module beforehand. MongoDB will automatically assign an `_id` field to your document (or you can assign this value by adding it to your dictionary in the code above) - you can get this value after the insert by doing `print new_data.inserted_id`